# remove text from tag and save in a database as integer in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, web-scraping, sqldatatypes

my project reads information from a site and save to database I want save price as integer but in this site with price there is "$" and with vehicle Mileage there is "miles"  ,how remove them and save to database as integer?

```
    price_car=car.find('h4',attrs={'data-test':'vehicleCardPricingBlockPrice'})
    work_car=car.find('div',attrs={'data-test':'vehicleMileage'})

   price=int(price_car.text)
   mile=int(price_car.text)
   cursor.execute('insert into infcars values(,%i,%i )'%(mile,price))
   cnx.commit()
```

Comment: Please use replace x=price_car.text      print(x.replace('$','')) will give you the result with $ removed (same for miles)

Comment: thanks but I got this error:invalid literal for int() with base 10: '$17,990'

Comment: How do you want to convert `'$17,990'`, `17990` (decimal point, comma as thousand separator) or `18` (comma as decimal point like in French)?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way using regex, the pattern `[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?` will match simple integers and decimals.

#### Regex explanation:

- `[0-9]+` : at least one number
- `(` : start of this group (for matching decimals)

  - `\.` : literal `.` for decimal separator
  - `[0-9]+` :  at least one number
  - `)`: end of the group
  - `?`: the group is optional

#### Code example:

```
import re
number_pattern = re.compile('[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?')

def find_number_in_string(s):
    try:
        search = number_pattern.search(s)
        if (search)
            result = search.group(0)  # Group 0 is 'all matched text'
            return float(result)
        return None
    except:
        return None

test1 = find_number_in_string("1250 miles")  # -> 1250
test2 = find_number_in_string("$24.99")  # -> 24.99
```

It doesn't account for things like thousand-separators or commas, please tweak to your requirements.